# Media Contacts Database?

Tags: data-request, media

Is there an open [media contacts database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_contacts_database), a sort of free version of [EasyMediaList.com](https://www.easymedialist.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python script [MondotimesScraper](https://github.com/Geremia/MondotimesScraper) can collect data from [Mondotimes.com](https://www.mondotimes.com/).